# C++: Why is this code giving me memory issues / undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, memory, mbed

**A bit of Background if you are interested...**

The next piece of code is an attempt at implementing a Packet Error Code generator using Cyclical Redundancy Check (CRC-15). This is used to detect communication data corruption. A more detailed introduction is unnecessary.

**Code and Issues**

init_PEC15_Table function is a lookup-table generator.

pec15 function takes a data input, calculates the address of the solution and find the result in the lookup-table.

data is a char array that I have assigned a value of 1 to. This is going to be passed to pec15.

Now, I found that **by just reordering the cout commands, the value of "stuffed pec", which is the output I am interested in, changes**. By reading online I understood that this could be due to the memory stack unexpectedly changing in a way that affects the result registers and that this could be due to out-of-bounds operations on other variables. Am I mistaken in my understanding?

Now, I am a beginner and this is very daunting. I might have made some gross mistakes that I am not aware of so please feel free to tear the code to shreds.
Also, if it matters, this code is running on an mbed LPC1768.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

unsigned short pec15Table[256];
const unsigned int CRC15_POLY = 0x4599;



void init_PEC15_Table() // Cyclical Redundancy Check lookup table generator function
{
    unsigned short rem;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        rem = i << 7;
        for (int bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit)
        {
            if (rem & 0x4000)
            {
                rem = ((rem << 1));
                rem = (rem ^ CRC15_POLY);
            }
            else
            {
                rem = ((rem << 1));
            }
        }
        pec15Table[i] = rem & 0xFFFF;
//        cout << hex << pec15Table [i] << endl;
    }
}

 unsigned short pec15(char* data, int lengt = 16)  //Takes data as an input,
{
     int rem, address;
     rem = 16;//PEC seed (intial PEC value)
    for (int i = 0; i < lengt; i++)
    {
        address = ((rem >> 7) ^ data[i]) & 0xff;//calculate PEC table address
        rem = (rem << 8) ^ pec15Table[address];
    }
    return (rem * 2);//The CRC15 has a 0 in the LSB so the final value must be multiplied by 2
}

int main()
{
    init_PEC15_Table();         //initialise pec table
    char data = (short) 0x1 ;   // Write 0x1 to char array containing the data 0x1
    char* dataPtr = &data;      // Create a pointer to that array

    unsigned short result = pec15(dataPtr);                    //Pass data pointer to pec calculator


    cout << "data in: " << (short) *dataPtr << endl;        //Print the short representation of the char data array (Outputs 1)
    cout << "size of data: " << sizeof(*dataPtr) << endl;   //Print the size of the char array (Outputs 1)
    cout << "stuffed pec: " << result << endl;                 //Print the output of the pec calculation    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: Can you use valgrind or similar?

Comment: `char data = (short) 0x1` then `char* dataPtr = &data; ` then `unsigned short result = pec15(dataPtr);` look like UB to me. The length of a character is not 16 bytes.

Comment: Gneral note: When doing bit manipulation you should use unsigned type.  They come with stronger guarantees than signed integers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I am using mbed's online compiler and it does not have a debugger, which means I have to do it manually. But thanks JETM for redirecting me towards that, I will give it a go.

Comment: drescherjm but for what reason?

Comment: ***I am using mbed's online compiler and it does not have a debugger, which means I have to do it manually.*** My advice is to develop your code on a PC with an IDE. When it comes time to submit you can use the online compiler.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the tip will try that

Comment: Your default parameter assumes the size of the data you pass is 16 bytes. But the actual pointer points to a single `char` nothing more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you've written here does not sync with the comments you've written:

```
char data = (short) 0x1 ;   // Write 0x1 to char array containing the data 0x1
char* dataPtr = &data;      // Create a pointer to that array
```

The first line does not write anything to a character array. Rather, it creates a `char` variable whose numeric value is 1. As a note, the cast to `short` here isn't needed and has no effect - did you mean to write something else?

The second line does not create a pointer to an array. Rather, it creates a pointer to the `data` variable. You could potentially think of this as a pointer to an array of length one, but that's probably not what you meant to do.

The two above lines don't by themselves do anything bad. The next line, however, is a real problem:

```
unsigned short result = pec15(dataPtr);                    //Pass data pointer to pec calculator
```

Remember that `pec15` has a second argument that's supposed to denote the length of the data passed in. Since you didn't specify it, it defaults to 16. However, your `dataPtr` pointer only points to a single `char` value, not 16 `char` values, so this results in undefined behavior.

I'm not sure how to fix this because I don't have a good sense for the intent behind your code. Did you mean to make a sixteen-element array? Did you mean to create an array filled with the value `0x1`? The correct fix here depends on the answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks yeah, the cast doesn't make any sense. Also on the second line I meant array of bits (the byte im pointing to), shouldn't have put it that way. And yes the third line is what was causing the problem. I was mixing up length to be the number of bits, not bytes. I am still very patchy.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
unsigned short result = pec15(dataPtr, 1);
```

otherwise `lengt` is 16 (has default value). I'd also advice to remove default value of `lengt`, as it makes little sense in context of `pec15` function.

Comment: Thanks @Radoslaw it was that line. I was mixing up the number of bits with the number of bytes...